# Delphi FastMM4 how read MemoryManager_EventLog.txt?

Tags: delphi, memory-management, memory-leaks, fastmm

I have added FastMM4  to my project for detect a memory leak

```
program MyProg;

uses
  {$IFDEF DEBUG}
  FastMM4,
  {$ENDIF}
  ...other uses
```

on form close FastMM4 produce a `MemoryManager_EventLog.txt`, with all leak block.

This is an example:

```
    --------------------------------2019/6/19 9:49:25--------------------------------
A memory block has been leaked. The size is: 20

This block was allocated by thread 0x558, and the stack trace (return addresses) at the time was:
4075D2 [System.pas][System][@GetMem$qqri][4614]
40ABAF [System.pas][System][TObject.NewInstance$qqrv][16452]
40B3D6 [System.pas][System][@ClassCreate$qqrpvzc][17790]
40AD20 [System.pas][System][TObject.$bctr$qqrv][16516]
F3BEF6 [NdST.pas][NdST][TFinder.$bctr$qqrp14System.TObject][1011]
11157D1 [SuperNode.pas][SuperNode][TSuperNode.$bctr$qqrp14System.TObject][993]
D1D840 [Network.pas][Network][TNetwork.Create$qqrv][968]
F3A70D [NdST.pas][NdST][TNdST.$bctr$qqrp14System.TObject][177]
F3B658 [NdST.pas][NdST][TNdSTCAP.$bctr$qqrp14System.TObject][652]
10A4CCA [Print.pas][Print][TPrint.CreateCollection$qqrv][4274]
10A2773 [Print.pas][Print][TPrint.CreateItem$qqrv][3031]

The block is currently used for an object of class: TList

The allocation number is: 53883

Current memory dump of 256 bytes starting at pointer address 7EBA5360:
48 FA 49 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7C C4 2D 79 00 00 00 00 E0 4B BA 7E
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9C CD 41 00 00 00 00 00 7C D2 00 00 D2 75 40 00 AF AB 40 00 D6 B3 40 00
1A 72 11 01 29 AD 40 00 F8 57 11 01 40 D8 D1 00 0D A7 F3 00 58 B6 F3 00 CA 4C 0A 01 73 27 0A 01
58 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
20 AD 40 00 B8 AB 40 00 D1 57 11 01 F4 1B 0B 01 22 4D 0A 01 87 27 0A 01 0A 48 11 01 52 6E 11 01
H  ú  I  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  |  Ä  -  y  .  .  .  .  à  K  º  ~
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  œ  Í  A  .  .  .  .  .  |  Ò  .  .  Ò  u  @  .  ¯  «  @  .  Ö  ³  @  .
.  r  .  .  )  ­  @  .  ø  W  .  .  @  Ø  Ñ  .  .  §  ó  .  X  ¶  ó  .  Ê  L  .  .  s  '  .  .
X  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  x  ï  ï  †
<  -  .  .  À  F  ¼  ~  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  ‡  .  .  y  .  .  .  .  .  Q  º  ~
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  €  Ò  .  .  Ò  u  @  .  ¯  «  @  .  Ö  ³  @  .
   ­  @  .  ¸  «  @  .  Ñ  W  .  .  ô  .  .  .  "  M  .  .  ‡  '  .  .  .  H  .  .  R  n  .  .
```

The leak seem to be caused by TList, but I free every TList. Is `TList.Free` not sufficient?

Comment: Too many questions. One question at a time here. We don't do tutorials, they are explicitly off topic. You'd be far better asking at Delphi Praxis.

Comment: The most important thing is the stack trace at time of allocation. That's the thing you didn't destroy. Often object A owns object B and they both leak. So even though you destroyed B in A's destructor, if you don't destroy A then they both leak.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan then, i must destroy every object into the TList before destroi the TList?

Comment: Who knows? We don't. We can't see any code. Did you read my comments telling you that this is off topic here?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't see too many questions here.

Comment: @Charlie Question was edited. Edit makes the correct close reason "off topic, question needs mcve"

Comment: All we can gleam from the log is that `TPrint.CreateItem()` is being called, and the object it creates is internally creating a `TList`, and that `TList` is not being freed. Maybe the returned object is not being freed by the caller? Maybe the object's destructor is not freeing the `TList` that the constructor created? Nobody here can say for sure, as we don't have the source code for either `TPrint` or the caller.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you create objects and save their references to TList, it is essential that you free them before the TList is freed.

```
for I := 0 to aList.Count-1 do
   anObjectType(aList[I]).Free;
```

If you want your objects to be freed automatically, use `TObjectList` with `OwnsObjects` parameter set. `TObjectList` frees the memory of all its objects when it is destroyed.

Comment: Not a fan of an answer that doesn't actually address the question (even when it is clearly off topic) and also speculates on the code being used.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What other evidence is needed, David, than OP's acceptance of my answer that his problem is addressed. Also, I don't think it is off topic.

Comment: The fact that the answer was accepted doesn't change anything. As it stands in this topic, we have solution without a problem!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Here is the question "but I free every TList. Is TList.Free not sufficient?". And above is the answer.

Comment: What if the thing that the list is holding was allocated with `New`? In your profile, you asked us to tell you why we downvoted. I did that. Enough.

Comment: The log message says that a single `TList` is not being freed. But this answer shows freeing the contents of a `TList`, not freeing the `TList` itself.  The answer does not match the question. I downvoted it for that reason.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You first claimed that you are not a fan - because the answer doesn't address the issue. You then took a U turn when I proved you were wrong by pointing out how the answer address the issue. Secondly, FYI - TObjectList doesn't support record types which you can allocate memory with new. So, you are further wrong David.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Look at the question. "Is TList.Free not sufficient?" This means OP knows that he has to free the TList and wonders what else need to be done. I showed in the answer what ELSE to be done. The OP got it intuitively :)

Comment: @CharlieH "*... and wonders what else need to be done*" - that is not how I interpret the OP's question at all. Nothing said in the question implies that. And besides, if the `TList` in question were being populated with objects that were not being freed, they would show up in the leak report as well. But the question asked is only about a single `TList` object, not about a group of objects.

Comment: It doesn't address the question (both the pre-edit question and the post-edit question). The question should be closed (in both pre-edit and post-edit form). Nothing in the question talks about what the `TList` holds. The report shows that in fact a `TList` has been leaked.

Comment: *"FYI - TObjectList doesn't support record types which you can allocate memory with new."* As I am quite sure you are aware, I know perfectly well what TObjectList is. But that's not the subject of the question. The leak report says TList. The question text says TList. You are putting words in my mouth, let me take them out again.

Comment: My problem with the question (I didn't downvote) is this: The title for the question is asking about Delphi reading a FastMM4 MemoryManager_EventLog.txt file and the inside the question there is a different question about freeing list items. This doesn't help people who are searching for solutions to problems.

Answer (score 0):

**So, how to read a FastMM log?**

The most relevant section is the one that states "the stack trace (return addresses) at the time was:" where
you will see a listing like the one below. This is what is called a stack trace.

A stack trace shows the execution path of your program; which function called which function.

First, it is good to know that for each line in the log:

- the first number is the memory addres where that function resides (EXE file)
- the last number in brackets is the source code line number where the function resides (PAS file).

We start reading from the bottom.

So, we can see that all started in the Print.pas unit. The CreateItem method of TPrint object
called CreateCollection which tried to create a new object.
In the end (see the top lines) we end up in TObject's constructor. That construnctor is a class method: ClassCreate.
TObject.NewInstance means that the TObject was actually being created. There, the constructor allocated (normally) some memory for the TObject via GetMem.

Now, until this point, nothing wrong has happened.
We allocated some memory when we created an object. Not a big deal.
The error happened when the programmer forgot to release that memory back.
In other words, we created an object, and we never freed it.

Anyway, the log seems a bit weird because the stack trace shows some items being created.
So we need to go into the source code and check all places where we call TPrint.CreateItem.
If you have just one place where TPrint.CreateItem is called, you are very lucky. You just have to check where that new item SHOULD be released, because it obviously it isn't.
If you have just one place where TPrint.CreateItem is called, you are moderatelly lucky. You have to check EACH place.

---

However, then the log complaints that the TList itself is not released (does not complain about its items) - maybe the log is incomplete?

> The block is currently used for an object of class: TList

So, releasing that TList should be enough.
I guess, what happens here is that some external code takes control over the items and releases them, while TList itself is not released.

---

Remember, if you don't see a detailed stack trace, it means that you need to:

- disable compiler optimizations
- in the same page, enable  stack frames
- enable map file